# Almacenar el numero de variable en una lista en pulp

Tags: python

Hola estoy intentando realizar un programa que resuelva problemas de programación lineal, el primer código que realice solo admite 2 variable x1 y x2 pero quiero que el usuario ingrese el numero de variable que el decida lo cual creo que ese valor tendría que estar almacenado en una lista pero no se como hacer eso. Ejemplo Ingresa el numero de variables: (3) y luego me pida que ingrese el valor de dichas variables x1:valor x2:valor x3:valor, este es el código antiguo

```
from pulp import *

# Crea un problema de maximización
problem = LpProblem("Programacion Lineal", LpMaximize)

# Definir las variables
x1 = LpVariable('X1', lowBound=0)  # Variable x1 >= 0
x2 = LpVariable('X2', lowBound=0)  # Variable x2 >= 0
variables = [x1, x2]

print("Ingresa la funcion objetivo\n")
num_x1 = float(input("Valor X1: "))
num_x2 = float(input("Valor X2: "))

# Función objetivo
objective_function = num_x1 * x1 + num_x2 * x2
problem += objective_function

num_restricciones = int(input("Ingrese el número de restricciones: "))

for i in range(num_restricciones):
    constraint_coeffs = [float(input(f"Coeficiente para {variable.name}: ")) * variable for variable in variables]

    operator = input("Operador (<=, >=, =): ")
    constraint_value = float(input("Valor de la restricción: "))  # Renombrar para evitar conflicto

    constraint_name = f"restriccion_{i + 1}"
    match operator:
        case "<=":
            problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) <= constraint_value, constraint_name
        case ">=":
            problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) >= constraint_value, constraint_name
        case "=":
            problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) == constraint_value, constraint_name

problem.solve()

# Imprimir resultados
print(f"Status: {problem.status}")
print(f"Función objetivo: {objective_function.value()}")
print(f"Valor de x1: {x1.value()}")
print(f"Valor de x2: {x2.value()}")
```

Estoy intentando que el nuevo codigo haga lo mismo pero solo que el usuario ingrese el numero de varibles que el decida

```
from pulp import *
from fractions import Fraction  # Importa la clase Fraction

print("1.- Para Maximizar")
print("2.- Para Minimizar")
variable_lp = int(input())

if variable_lp == 1:
    opc_lp = LpMaximize
elif variable_lp == 2:
    opc_lp = LpMinimize
else:
    print("Colocaste un valor incorrecto")

# Crea un problema de maximización
problem = LpProblem("Programacion Lineal", opc_lp)
num_variables = int(input("ingresa el numero de variables: "))

# Definir las variables
variables = [LpVariable(f"X{i}", lowBound=0) for i in range(num_variables)]

print("Ingresa la funcion objetivo\n")

obj_coefficients = [Fraction(input(f"X{i}: " * variable[i] for variable in variables))]

# Función objetivo
problem += lpSum([Fraction(obj_coefficients[i]) * variables[i] for i in range(num_variables)])

num_restricciones = int(input("Ingrese el número de restricciones: "))

for i in range(num_restricciones):
    print("Restriccion",i+1)
    constraint_coeffs = [Fraction(input(f"Coeficiente para {variable.name}: ")) * variable for variable in variables]

    operator = input("Operador (<=, >=, =): ")
    constraint_value = Fraction(input("Valor de la restricción: "))

    constraint_name = f"restriccion_{i + 1}"
    if operator == "<=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) <= constraint_value, constraint_name
    elif operator == ">=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) >= constraint_value, constraint_name
    elif operator == "=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) == constraint_value, constraint_name

problem.solve()

# Imprimir resultados
print(f"Status: {problem.status}")
print(f"Función objetivo: {problem.value()}")
```

cualquier consejo lo agradecería.

Comment: se ve interesante, dejame ver como te puedo ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema lo tienes en:

```
obj_coefficients = [Fraction(input(f"X{i}: " * variable[i] for variable in variables))]
```

- Tienes los paréntesis mal colocados, le estas pasando a `input` el generador al completo.
- El indice (`i`) debe generarse en el ciclo `for`.
- Si multiplicas por cada variable ya no es una lista de coeficientes, son los términos de la función.

Debería ser algo como:

```
obj_terms = [Fraction(input(f"X{i}: ")) * variables[i] for i in range(len(variables))]
```

pero es mucho mas simple iterar directamente sobre la lista de variables y usar el atributo `name`:

```
obj_terms = [Fraction(input(f"{variable.name}: ")) * variable for variable in variables]
```

Con lo anterior resuelto, la siguiente linea problemática es:

```
problem += lpSum([Fraction(obj_coefficients[i]) * variables[i] for i in range(num_variables)])
```

ya tienes los términos de la función objetivo en la lista anterior, basta con aplicar `lpSum`:

```
problem += lpSum(obj_terms)
```

No obstante te interesa mantener una referencia a la función objetivo para luego obtener los resultados, por lo que deberías hacer algo como:

```
objective_function = lpSum(obj_coefficients)
problem += objective_function
```

El siguiente error esta en:

```
print(f"Función objetivo: {problem.value()}")
```

el método `LpProblem.value()` no existe, aquí es donde necesitas la referencia a la función objetivo que comentábamos antes, debe ser:

```
print(f"Función objetivo: {objective_function.value()}")
```

Por ultimo, si quieres obtener los valores de cada variable puedes simplemente usar un `for`:

```
for variable in variables:
    print(f"Valor de {variable.name}: {variable.value()}")
```

El código completo seria:

```
from pulp import lpSum, LpMaximize, LpMinimize, LpProblem, LpVariable
from fractions import Fraction  # Importa la clase Fraction


print("1.- Para Maximizar")
print("2.- Para Minimizar")
variable_lp = int(input())

if variable_lp == 1:
    opc_lp = LpMaximize
elif variable_lp == 2:
    opc_lp = LpMinimize
else:
    print("Colocaste un valor incorrecto")

# Crea un problema de maximización
problem = LpProblem("Programacion_Lineal", opc_lp)
num_variables = int(input("ingresa el numero de variables: "))

# Definir las variables
variables = [LpVariable(f"X{i + 1}", lowBound=0) for i in range(num_variables)]

print("Ingresa los coeficientes de la función objetivo\n")
obj_terms = [
    Fraction(input(f"{variable.name}: ")) * variable for variable in variables
    ]

# Función objetivo
objective_function = lpSum(obj_terms)
problem += objective_function

num_restricciones = int(input("Ingrese el número de restricciones: "))

for i in range(num_restricciones):
    print("Restriccion", i + 1)
    constraint_coeffs = [
        Fraction(input(f"Coeficiente para {variable.name}: ")) * variable
        for variable in variables
        ]

    operator = input("Operador (<=, >=, =): ")
    constraint_value = Fraction(input("Valor de la restricción: "))

    constraint_name = f"restriccion_{i + 1}"
    if operator == "<=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) <= constraint_value, constraint_name
    elif operator == ">=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) >= constraint_value, constraint_name
    elif operator == "=":
        problem += lpSum(constraint_coeffs) == constraint_value, constraint_name

problem.solve()

# Imprimir resultados
print(f"Status: {problem.status}")
print(f"Función objetivo: {objective_function.value()}")
for variable in variables:
    print(f"Valor de {variable.name}: {variable.value()}")
```

Comment: muchas gracias solucionaste muchas de mis dudas es cierto ahora me fijo bien y obj_coefficients le estaba pasando el input completo y no realizaba el ciclo for también no encontraba la manera de que me imprima los valores de las variables gracias por solucionarme esa duda también era con un for que obtiene los valores de variables